# importing flask_bcrypt not working on ubuntu 16.04 environment

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I'm building an app with `flask` on my ubuntu machine and I needed to import the `flask bcrypt`.

I used the code line below:

```
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
```

I got the error that:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_bcrypt'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed it correctly accordingly of your python version:

`pip install flask-bcrypt && pip3 install flask-bcrypt`

If you are using some kind of envs firstly install it outside env cuz its recommanded to do so and then do:
`pipenv install flask-bycrypt`

If you use pycharm then you  need to go to file -> setting and then set a path to flask-bcrypt.

Comment: I followed same command, then also getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

the issue has been resolved, it was related to pip. i used below sentence to install flask-bcrypt

> python -m pip install flask-bcrypt